Transferring tar data between servers started taking much longer
I have a nightly backup that transfers about 100gb of data from AIX server A to AIX server B using the following command in a script.
tar cf - ./DATA | ssh server_b 'cd /DISKCOPY ; tar xf - '

This has been running for months consistently taking about 30 minutes but, as of a few days ago, has been taking progressively much longer every day without much change in the size of data. 2 hours, then 6 hours, now it's almost up to 24 hours. The tar process is visible using "ps -ef | grep tar" on both servers and the data can be seen slowly overwriting the contents of /DISKCOPY but I can't tell whether it's the tar cf or the tar xf or the transfer over the network that is deteriorating.
There doesn't seem to be a problem with the network speed and it looks like there is plenty of room for the data in /DISKCOPY on server_b.
Is there something that could make tar (either cf or xf) start to take a long time? A temporary location that is running out of space or something? Or could it be a problem with the disk?

As an aside, do you have rsync installed on either/both servers? If not, could you?

We do actually have a real-time data replication solution successfully running, this copy is a backup-of-a-backup so not vital but I think everyone wants to work out what the root of this issue is in case there is an underlying problem.

Source disk, network, destination disk. Three points of potential contention. Also CPU and memory resource on each server

Thanks. I've done some manual copies both locally and across the network and they seem to be going OK...meanwhile the scheduled copy is still chugging along. We'll do some more digging and update if we find anything.
